# auto div height working for the first container but not the second

Tags: css, css-position

I have photos that are a mixture of portrait and landscape and would like the container to accomodate either when uploaded,

```
height: auto
```

will work for the first container (a portrait picture) but then stay the same height for the next container (landscape picture) but the width will change as its supposed to.

Here is a photo of what i mean...

[image]

Here is the html:

```
      <div class="picture-holder">
        <div class="picture-single">
          <div class="picture-title">
            <p><%= count%>. <%= link_to "#{x.title}", picture_path(x.id) %> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="entry-image">
            <%= link_to picture_path(x) do %>
              <% if !x.image.landscape.url.nil? %>
                <% image_tag x.image.landscape.url %>
              <% else %>
                <% image_tag x.image.portrait.url %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-details">
            <p>Uploaded by <%= link_to "#{x.user.username}(#{user_score(x.user.id)})", user_path(x.user) %> <br /><%= link_to "Comments(#{x.comments.count})", picture_path(x) %> </p> |
            <div class="">
              <% if is_yours?(x.id) %>
                <span class="text-green"> <%= link_to "Upvote", like_picture_path(x), method: :put %> </span>
                <span class="badge"><%= x.get_upvotes.size%></span>
                <span class="text-red"> <%= link_to "Downvote", unlike_picture_path(x), method: :put %> </span>
                <span class="badge"><%= x.get_downvotes.size%></span>
              <% else %>
                Upvote
                <span class="badge"><%= x.get_upvotes.size%></span>
                Downvote
                <span class="badge"><%= x.get_downvotes.size%></span>
              <% end %>
              <% if is_yours?(x.id) %>
                <span><p> <%= link_to "Report", new_report_path(:picture_id => x.id) %> </p></span>
              <% else %>
                <span class="text-red"><p> <%= link_to "Delete", picture_path(x), method: :delete %></p></span>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
    .picture-holder{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      border: solid black;
      border-radius: 35px;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 60px 40px 0px 40px;
      display: flex;
    }

    .picture-single{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .picture-title{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .entry-image{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .picture-details{
      margin: 0px 30px 0px 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

My css skills arent up to scratch (yet) and I can't find a solution, so any ideas on how to get the height to accommodate the container will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Look into `display: flex;`

Comment: Do you want landscape images to be cropped?

Comment: Use CSS-pseudo class :not for the second element - .picture-single:not(:nth-child(2n)) {height: auto;}

Comment: Im just looking to get rid of the white space below the landscape pictures

Comment: @Alex there will be more images uploaded randomly, these are just a example

Comment: The default value of the align-items property is stretch, that's why flex-items have the same height, which is dictated by the height of the "tallest" item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the properties of using flexbox, children with identical heights. A solution would be to just fall back into blocks and floats.

The best thing you can do is use the `align-items` property.

```css
.list { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-item {
  width: 200px;
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <img src="http://baconmockup.com/250/200" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eveniet.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Code partially taken from [Lotte Jackson](http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox)

Answer (score 2):

That's due to `display: flex` for `.picture-holder`, which by default adjusts the heights of the items. Just erase it. Or you can add `align-content: flex-start` if you have to keep flex.

Comment: Removing flex didnt change anything unfortunately nor did adding flex start

Comment: `align-content` should be `align-items`